# How to add a custom button to each field of a Custom Post Types Admin Screen

Tags: custom-post-types

The best way to show you what I want is a picture:

[image: here]

I would like to add a button on the red area in order to create a special action concerning the *Chambre1*.

I was looking foor something similar to the "*manage_posts_columns*" filter that we use to create new columns in the *Custom Post Types Admin Screen* but I found nothing.

Anyone has a solution for this ?

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are similar filters and actions for custom post type (replace **$post_type** with the name of your post type):

To add new columns filter is: **manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns**. This filter has one argument, list of all columns, and you need to add your column, and return results.

To display content of the column, action is **manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column**. This action passes the name of the column and post ID. You need to echo the data you want to display, but make sure you check if the column is indeed yours by checking the column name.

```
add_action('manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column', 'my_custom_column', 10, 2);
function my_custom_column($column, $post_id) {
  if ($column == {$my_column_name}) {
    echo '<button>My Button</button>'
  }
}
```

Replace **{$post_type}** with the actual name of your post type, and replace **{$my_column_name}** with the name of the column you have added through the **manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns** filter.

This is simplified code, you need to create the button you need to use, and handle what the button does.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I think you did not read my post correctly, indeed I already know how to add a column, what I need is to add a button

Comment: When adding a new column you can basically insert everything there, up to you if it's a button or whatever.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a basic example of adding content into column field.